# Is using too many IF statements a problem? SWIFT

Tags: swift, if-statement

I am currently completing a challenge on hacker rank called compare the triplets (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/compare-the-triplets/problem), and I was just wondering if using too many IF statements is considered bad programming practice? What are the alternatives other than using switch statements. Please see my code solution below :

```
import Foundation

func compareTriplets(a: [Int], b: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    
  var compareArray = [0,0]
    
    if a[0] == b[0]{
      compareArray[0] = compareArray[0]
    }
    if a[0] < b[0]{
      compareArray[0] = compareArray[0] + 1
    }
    if a[1] < b[1] {
        compareArray[0] = compareArray[0] + 1
    }
    if a[2] < b[2] {
        compareArray[0] = compareArray[0] + 1
    }
    if a[0] > b[0]{
      compareArray[1] = compareArray[1] + 1
    }
    if a[1] > b[1] {
        compareArray[1] = compareArray[1] + 1
    }
    if a[2] > b[2] {
        compareArray[1] = compareArray[1] + 1
    }
    
    return compareArray
}

print(compareTriplets(a: [17,28,30], b: [99,28,8]))
```

Comment: It will make the code harder to read. You are using if instead of if/else which is not logical since if a == b there is no point in checking if a < b for instance. Since you are doing the same check for multiple indices one solution here is to introduce a function that does the comparisons (for one pair of values) and use it in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will expand a lot if you will have more and more elements in arrays you send.

Why not try something like

```
func compareTriplets(a: [Int], b: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var compareArray = [0,0]
    
    if a.count != b.count {
        return compareArray
    }
    for index in 0..<(a.count) {
        if a[index] > b[index] {
            compareArray[0] += 1
        }
        else if a[index] < b[index] {
            compareArray[1] += 1
        }
    }
    
    return compareArray
}
```

Of course, if array lengths can differ then you can take min or go to minimum array length.

Comment: Because my brain won't let me think like that, should I give up on programming?

Comment: NO! Not even close! You just need to keep practicing and codiing! DO NOT GIVE UP.

Comment: If you are interested in programming, you should keep going. Your brain don't let you think like that right now, but with a bit of practice you surely will ;)

Comment: @BabyProgrammer I had the same issues, try learning some other languages (c helped me a lot) and then come back to swift. It will open your eyes on a lot of basic concepts that may seem hard at the beginning